# Chinup away from bar

Tags: chin-ups

What is it called when you do a chinup but hold the chest away from the bar so the elbow makes a 90 degree angle at the top? I've been playing with this and found it gives a nice burn on triceps while making the pullup more difficult.

Does this exercise have a name?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like pulling to a position that is half way between a chin-up and a front lever.

I doubt there's any existing name for it, and very much doubt that it uses to triceps to any significant degree.